# displaying player lives/text Flash game CS6 AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I am coding a flash game using AS3 where the player begins with 3 lives, I want this to be displayed on the screen however it only displays the first letter "L" and no number(int Lives)

here is the relevent code (snippets)

I have a blank textbox with the name txtLives

```
var lives:int = 3;

txtLives.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateTextFields);

function updateTextFields(event:Event):void{
 var lives:int = 3;
 var str:String = "Lives ";
 txtLives.text = str + String(lives);
 }
```

Any help would be great appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your font is embedded on the text field by selecting the text field, then on the properties tab in the character section press the "Embed ..." button. Verify that the character sets you want are all checked.

[image]

Also in your function you can simplify it to:

```
function updateTextFields(event:Event):void
{
     txtLives.text = "Lives " + lives;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can enable the usage of device fonts.

[image: use device fonts]

Select the "Use Device fonts" and your code should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Lol if the trick by the guy above don't work then try to extend your text box.